# Showing recent uploads without registration

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a video hosting but I don't want a registration so I want to show the recent uploads via IP

This is what I have:

```
<?php
$query = $mysqli->query('SELECT `id`, `name`, `url` FROM videos WHERE ip LIKE "$ip"');
    while($run = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $video_id = $run['id'];
        $video_name = $run['name'];
        $video_url = $run['url'];
        ?>
        <div id="url">
            <input type="text" value="http://m1z.nl/videomage/view.php?video=<?php echo $video_url; ?>" style="width:80%;">
            <a href="http://m1z.nl/videomage/view.php?video=<?php echo $video_url; ?>"><button>Go!</button></a>
        </div>
        <?php

    }
    ?>
```

Now if I do this I cant get any images and I already store the ip's in my database
Screen:
http://scrshot.com/axg8

Comment: This seems fine except for the face that you are using an id for the div, but you are expecting multiple result. An id should be unique.
You should probably use equals instead of LIKE for the query as well.

Comment: if IP is an varchar column most likly it is use = instead of LIKE..

Comment: I did change LIKE to = and it doesn't work..

Answer (score -1):

Create a column "id" as an auto increment than simply append this into your query at the end "ORDER BY `id` DESC" than you can also define the limit as "LIMIT {INTEGER HERE}"